# How do I get the Word Variables to replace the number values in this ListBox Loop?

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have a school assignment that requires me to use a loop and some mathematical equations. What the project needs to accomplish is you type in a range at the top of numbers. Then in the text boxes below you type in a number and a word on each side. When you hit "Calculate" the program needs to replace all the MULTIPLES of the number you typed in with the WORD you typed below it. This should happen with both sets of numbers and words. Then if a number is a multiple of both it should display both words.

Here is a screen shot of my GUI to help you see what I mean.

[image]

This is the code so far and what it produces is a list or all the multiples just like I want...but it is just adding the word below the numbers.

How do I get it to replace the number with the word I want entered?

Thanks.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim intCounterHigh As Integer
    Dim intCounterLow As Integer

    Dim intMultipleLeft As Integer
    Dim intMultipleRight As Integer

    Dim strWordLeft As String
    Dim strWordRight As String

    intCounterHigh = txtCounterHigh.Text
    intCounterLow = txtCounterLow.Text



    strWordLeft = txtWordLeft.Text
    strWordRight = txtWordRight.Text

    intMultipleLeft = txtMultipleLeft.Text
    intMultipleRight = txtMultipleRight.Text



        While counter <= intCounterHigh - 1
            counter += 1
            lstResult.Items.Add(CStr(counter))


            If counter Mod intMultipleLeft < 1 Then
                lstResult.Items.Add(strWordLeft)
            End If

            If counter Mod intMultipleRight < 1 Then
                lstResult.Items.Add(strWordRight)
            End If

            If counter Mod intMultipleRight < 1 And counter Mod intMultipleLeft < 1 Then
                lstResult.Items.Add(strWordLeft & strWordRight)
            End If

        End While

End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    lstResult.Items.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub txtCounter_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCounterHigh.TextChanged

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that you've seen a bit more of data structures than what you show here. I'm not going to give you the full answer (that's not what we do here), but I will tell you that you already have the answer, you're just not seeing it. Let's approach this backwards, from most restrictive to least restrictive:

- If `counter` is a multiple of both numbers, you print your two words.
- If not, but `counter` is a multiple of the left number, you print the left word.
- If not, but `counter` is a multiple of the right number, you print the right word.
- If none of the above work, then you just print the number.

Those are the rules, right? Go forth, young grasshopper.

Comment: Ok, I THINK I see what your trying to say. But I'm still drawing a blank. I appreciate your help...but I'm still missing it.

Comment: You can chain `If`s with an `ElseIf` to look for another condition. Take a look at this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx).

Comment: So do I need to change my WHILE statement? Since WHILE is setting all of the numbers to populate then when they are multiples it has them add the word below it. If I remove the while statement and instead make the WHILE statement my variables it should replace it? Make it so if it is NOT a multiple then list the numbers? Am I on the right track?

Comment: The `While` itself seems fine. It's your conditions inside your `While` you need to check.

Comment: Also, make sure you initialize `counter` and start it at your lowest value.

Comment: OMG! I got it! But just like it said my low value is messed up. How can I set a range like that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38561/discussion-between-user2788749-and-mpelletier)